# Variogram fit using gstat package in R

Tags: r, kriging, gstat

The following code is for predicting v value at three locations with the kriging method in R using gstat package.

```
library(gstat);
library(sp);
walk470 <- read.table("D:/kriging/walk470.txt",header=T)
attach(walk470)
coordinates(walk470) = ~x+y
walk.var1 <- variogram(v ~ x+y,data=walk470,width=10)
plot(walk.var1,xlab="Distance",ylab="Semivariance",main="Variogram for V, Lag Spacing = 5")
model1.out <- fit.variogram(walk.var1,vgm(70000,"Sph",40,20000))
plot(walk.var1, model=model1.out,xlab="Distance",ylab="Semivariance",main="Variogram for V, Lag Spacing = 10")
predpts <- matrix(c(60,190,225,50,110,185),ncol=2,byrow=T)
predpts.g <- data.frame(x=predpts[,1],y=predpts[,2])
coordinates(predpts.g) <- ~x+y
g <- gstat(NULL,"new.v",v~1,data=walk470,model=model1.out)
three.pred <- predict(g,predpts.g)
print(three.pred)
```

I want to know why for fitting variogram model, we need to provide the sill, nugget and range value beforehand using vgm() method. From kriging theory, I thought we have to calculate these values by minimizing the WLS objective function.

~Regards,
Chandan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since one of your parameters is the range of a spherical variogram model, the optimization problem solved by WLS is nonlinear. Nonlinear optimization typically requires initial values (see e.g. `?optim`), and that is what you pass to the initial `vgm` call. The actual value passed is also somewhat important: if it is far outside a range of reasonable values (nearly zero or VERY large), the fit will not succeed.

If you would only fit sill and nugget (passing `fit.ranges=TRUE` to `fit.variogram`), the problem would be linear and could in principle be done without initial value. In that case, arbitrary values far outside the data range will still work.

Comment: Does that mean we have to provide the initial values according to the empirical variogram plot?